# Syntax Error MySQL Update

Tags: mysql

I'm running a pass-through from access to MYSQL and trying to run an update query but keep getting a syntax error. I am brand new to MYSQL. It looks correct to me so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. The query works in Access.

Access Query:

```
UPDATE [ProductInformation-ODBC] 
INNER JOIN TempPrice 
ON [ProductInformation-ODBC].FirstOfSku =TempPrice.FirstOfSku 
SET [ProductInformation-ODBC].Price = [TempPrice]![Price];
```

MYSQL:

```
UPDATE ProductInformation-ODBC
INNER JOIN TempPrice ON ProductInformation-ODBC.FirstOfSku = 
TempPrice.FirstOfSku 
SET ProductInformation-ODBC.Price = TempPrice.Price
```

Comment: `ProductInformation-ODBC` must be in quotes or have no `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `ProductInformation-ODBC` P 
INNER JOIN TempPrice ON P.FirstOfSku = 
TempPrice.FirstOfSku 
SET P.Price = TempPrice.Price
```

Don't use `-` in the table name and choose a proper name for your tables

In the complex queries use an alias name for your tables like `P` on the code above